# Javascript with validation and submit with alert results

Tags: javascript

I have tried everything in javascript to get the submit button to show
in the alert all the input fields.

Example.  When a user fills out a form, it validates, then clicks on
submit to show the results in the alert such as name, cost, address
and phone and so on.  I am trying to practice on javascript but can't
get the desire results I wanted.

Can someone help!

Here is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
// Form validation code will come here.     
var Num1 = document.getElementById('1stTotal').value;
var Num2 = document.getElementById('2ndTotal').value;
var Num3 = document.getElementById('3rdTotal').value;
var Total = Num1 + Num2 + Num3;
grandTotal.value = Total;
function validate() {
    if (document.myForm.Name.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide your name!");
        document.myForm.Name.value.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.myForm.Street.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide your Street!");
        document.myForm.Street.value.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.myForm.City.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide your City!");
        document.myForm.City.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.myForm.Postal.value == "" || isNaN(document.myForm.Postal.value) || document.myForm.Postal.value.length != 7) {
        alert("Please provide a Postal in the format xxx-xxx.");
        document.myForm.Postal.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.myForm.Telephone.value == "" || isNaN(document.myForm.Telephone.value) || document.myForm.Telephone.value.length != 12) {
        alert("Please provide a Telephone in the format xxx-xxx-xxxx.");
        document.myForm.Telephone.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var emailID = document.myForm.Email.value;
    atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
    dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || (dotpos - atpos < 2)) {
        alert("Please provide a valid email.");
        document.myForm.Email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.myForm.CardNo.value == "" || isNaN(document.myForm.CardNo.value) || document.myForm.CardNo.value.length != 16) {
        alert("Please provide a Credit Card Number in the format 1234567890123456.");
        document.myForm.CardNo.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.myForm.Expiry.value == "" || isNaN(document.myForm.Expiry.value) || document.myForm.Expiry.value.length != 10) {
        alert("Please provide a Expiry in the format MM-DD-YYYY.");
        document.myForm.Expiry.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return (true);
}
function greeting() {
    alert("Hello " + Name + "," + "<br />" + "Your book order includes:");
} < /script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use core native javascript, you'll probably have issues related to browsers different interpretation/rendering/compatibility.

I would strongly suggest you to use a js framework like [mootools](http://www.mootools.net) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Then you will be able both to really easily select the form elements and also to properly validate the form.

Of course, you'll need first to study a little the choosen framework, but be sure you'll be very happy then :)

EDIT: also, bear in mind that any code that references any html element, must be called AFTER the element is created. In other words, you should wrap the function calls in an onload or ondomready event.

Comment: OP mentioned that he/she is learning JS, so better don't suggest any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE don't have one alert firing after another. Very annoying UI. Don't return after each invalid input, either. Do it all at once.

Instead, build a string of messages for each invalid input. Start with an empty string. At the end, if the string has a length, alert it. Otherwise, you're valid.

so the first part might look like this:

```
var str = "";
function validate() {
if (document.myForm.Name.value == "") {
    str += "Please provide your name!\n"; // use a newline in alerts
}
// etc.
//
if (str.length > 0) {
    alert(str);
}
// but there are better ways than alert, too.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do it easily using "onmouseover" to call the function and all the "else if" statements you want. The alerts will address each required input field one at a time without a series of alerts one after the other.

```js
function subCheck() {
  if (document.myForm.Contact.value === "") {
   alert("Contact Name Required");
   document.myForm.Contact.focus();
  }
  else if (document.myForm.Email.value === "") {
   alert("Contact Email Required");
   document.myForm.Email.focus();
  }
 }
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
Contact Name: <input type="text" name="Contact"><br /><br />
Contact Email: <input type="text" name="Email"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="SUBMIT" onmouseover="subCheck()"></form>
```